# UML Class Diagram (Java Related) Difference Between Dotted and Dashed Lines

Tags: java, uml

Are there a  difference between these two associations? I want to create Java Program with this.

[image]

If there is a difference between those two, What are they? Any example codes are highly appreciated.

Thanks for your time,
Cheers

Comment: Those are no associaitons. The top one looks like a dependency. The bottom one is not a valid UML connector. The author probably meant to show a Realization, but that has a non filled, closed arrow head.

Comment: The left two filled arrows are also wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Is just a dependency. This Board Interface does not have Piece enum as a part of the class but works with it.

For example: `enum Piece{GREEN, BLUE}`, and

```
class BoardFactory {

  Board create(Piece piece) {
    if(piece == Piece.GREEN) {
      return new GreenBoard();
    }
  }

}
```

2. This one is even more simple. It is a realization of the interface.
   `BoardController implements BoardUI`

Comment: The second one is probably *meant* to be a realization, but it isn't currently. A Realization has a non filled arrow head.

Comment: Correct, thank you. Looks like a bug with a tool that has generated this UML.